# windows 10 IOT universal windows app, how do i install an app programatically

Tags: installation, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Running win10 IOT core on the raspberry pi 2 and I'm wondering if the following is possible:

1) have a headless app running that is called 'version checker'.  in addition, have multiple other headless apps running.

2) if a new version of an app is available, it downloads the package

3) once new package is downloaded, it installs the app

If this is possible, where should I start?

Comment: and the last question should be, how to start the app from another app or from the powershell console...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not against writing the app in HTML/JS, you could write it as a Hosted Web App. 
It's really similar to a Chrome / FirefoxOS app, which caches your code on the device, and hits your site to see if there are any changes since it last loaded, and update itself if it does.

Here's a [blog](http://www.intergen.co.nz/blog/Jonny-Lin/dates/2015/6/Native-or-web-Microsoft-blurs-the-lines/) that I wrote a while back.